# Determine if sequence described by $a_1=1$, $a_n=a_{n-1}+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}} $ is increasing

Tags: calculus

From listing the first few terms, I suspect that the sequence is increasing, so I wanted to use mathematical induction to verify my suspicion.

I have assumed that $a_k<a_{k+1}$, I don't see how I can obtain $a_{k+1}<a_{k+2}$ because $\frac{1}{a_k}>\frac{1}{a_{k+1}}$

Comment: you can see that each time we add something positive so it is increasing!

Comment: All terms are positive, so $a_n = a_{n-1} +1/a_{n-1} > a_{n-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base case:

$$1+\dfrac11>1\implies a_2>a_1.$$

Inductive step:

$$a_n=a_{n-1}+\frac1{a_{n-1}}>a_{n-1}
\\\implies a_{n-1}>0
\\\implies a_n=a_{n-1}+\dfrac1{a_{n-1}}>0
\\\implies a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac1{a_n}>a_n.$$

---

Anyway, it is much simpler to establish $a_n>0$ ($1>0$ and $a_n>0\implies a_{n+1}=a_n+\dfrac1{a_n}>a_n>0)$ which is enough to justify the growth.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence is positive. Easy proof by induction.

Then $a_n - a_{n-1} = 1/a_{n-1} >0$ proving that the sequence is increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Hint, prove the following theorems in order:

> **Theorem 1.** $a_n$ is positive.
>
> **Theorem 2.** $a_n > a_{n-1}$

Answer (score 0):

The sequence is increasing.

Since $a_{n-1}>0, $ it follows that $\dfrac1{a_{n-1}}>0$, and therefore that $a_n=a_{n-1}+\dfrac1{a_{n-1}}>a_{n-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Prove that $a_n > 0$ for all $n$.

Then use that 
$$
a_n = a_{n-1} + \frac{1}{a_{n-1}} > a_{n-1}, 
$$ 
since $1 / a_{n-1} > 0$.